# Add Key to (IMA) Keyring at boot or at kernel compile time

Tags: linux-kernel, compiling

I know that one can add keys with keyctl to a keyring.

Since the key I want to add is a key for the IMA/EVM subsystem, it has to be loaded at the earliest possible moment in the boot process or already exist (compiled into kernel).

Is there a way to compile the Linux kernel (4.1) with a set of keys attached to a keyring? Or can I just put the keys I want to be loaded at boot in a special folder (from which they are loaded on boot)?

Answer (score 0):

Version 4.1 allows to load certificates for IMA by putting them into the path defined in "CONFIG_IMA_X509_PATH" (option within the "Security Options config menu).

A builtin public key for the kernel is generated in the root directory of compilation by ticking the configuration option "CONFIG_IMA_TRUSTED_KEYRING" in ("Security Options").

However, it seems that in 4.1 at boot the kernel does not verify if the ima certificate is signed with a key of the trusted keyring (seems to be fixed in later versions).